# How to ask the DB if a file exists from a .js in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, gql

what I'm trying to do is have a upload button to upload files to our storage system. I'm using Google App Engine with Python. Also HTML and Javascript for views.

For that, we have a HTML, and a.js that asks the user if he's sure that he wants to overwrite a file. For that overwriting question, I need to ask the Database to know if it exists,and so if the question should be asked or not...

The thing is I don't know even where to start. I have this confirm() text shown to the user, and a GQL database, but I don't know how to make a question. For example, I upload via a URL, but then I don't have a response for that, and also I don't want to pass a question (name of the file,...) to the database via URL...

Do you have any idea of what path should I follow? Am I trying something impossible or without any sense?

Thanks a lot!

I add some code:

this is the HTML form where we ask the user to upload a file:

```
<form id="up_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ current_user.id }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ group.id }}"/>
                <p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" id="file_name"/></p>
                <p><input type="button" value="Upload" onClick="seguro_sobreescribir(filename,{{ current_user.id }},{{ group.id }})"/></p>
            </form>
```

and this is the javascript that currently tries to send information to our application in google engine when someone clicks the upload button:

```
function Request(function_name, opt_argv) {
  if (!opt_argv)
    opt_argv = new Array();

  // Find if the last arg is a callback function; save it
  var callback = null;
  var len = opt_argv.length;
  if (len > 0 && typeof opt_argv[len-1] == 'function') {
    callback = opt_argv[len-1];
    opt_argv.length--;
  }
  var async = (callback != null);

  // Build an Array of parameters, w/ function_name being the first parameter
  var params = new Array(function_name);
  for (var i = 0; i < opt_argv.length; i++) {
    params.push(opt_argv[i]);
  }
  var body = JSON.stringify(params);

  // Create an XMLHttpRequest 'POST' request w/ an optional callback handler
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.open('POST', 'https://safeshareapp.appspot.com/upload', async);

  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", body.length);
  req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  if (async) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        var response = null;
        try {
         response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
         response = req.responseText;
        }
        callback(response);
      }
    }
  }

  // Make the actual request
  req.send(body);
}


// Comprobar si existe, y si existe, preguntar si se quiere sobreescribir
function seguro_sobreescribir(filename,user_id,group_id)
{   

        var resp=confirm("Seguro que quiere sobreescribir el archivo "+filename.value+" del usuario "+user_id+" del grupo "+group_id+"?");      

        if(resp)
        {           
            var result = Request('Upload',[filename,user_id,group_id]);
            alert("Hemos hecho request "+ result);
        }       

}
```

And this is the RequestHandler that should handle our request:

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """ Allows the functions defined in the RPCMethods class to be RPCed."""
    def __init__(self):
        webapp.RequestHandler.__init__(self)
        self.methods = RPCMethods()

    def post(self):

        args = simplejson.loads(self.request.body)
        func, args = args[0], args[1:]

        if func[0] == '_':
            self.error(403) # access denied
            return

        func = getattr(self.methods, func, None)
        if not func:
            self.error(404) # file not found
            return

        result = func(*args)
        self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(result))

class RPCMethods:

    def Upload(self, *args):

        status = -1
        fileitem = args[0]        
        userid = args[1]
        groupid=args[2]    

        return status

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/upload', RPCHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The fact is that the return status gives us a undefined back at the javascript.
We don't know if we are not uploading the file and if so, how to do it. That's because we have 2 things that we don't know how to put together:

- The normal "input type=file, method=post, and submit input type=submit button of a HTML form
- Our connection via RequestHandler to the google app engine etc.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are you using any Python framework (e.g. django, web2py...). You can also find some tools that could help you right there.

Comment: No, JMax, we are just using normal google app engine & python with html and javascript, because it's a short project and we didn't know the wonders of Django before starting :D

Comment: How are you storing and organizing files? There's no need for filename to be a unique constraint, depending on how you store them; the answer to your question depends entirely on how you're storing and organizing things.

Comment: Hi Nick!
we are just putting them in Dropbox via Dropbox API.
To do that we have python code that calls dropbox functions. That works.
The thing is that we don't know how to connect the Javascript that should upload the file to the RequestHandler.
I mean, we think we are connecting with the RequestHandler but we don't know how to pass the file.

We are using this example, the "post" one.

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/appengine/articles/rpc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

Implement a servlet that can answer the question given a filename; it could return a '0' or '1' (or whatever you choose) as its HTTP response depending on whether the file exists. Then make an XmlHttpRequest POST to that servlet from your javascript with the filename as a POST parameter. Depending on the return of the XmlHttpRequest, show UI to the user asking to confirm.

Comment: That looks like what I want. But how can I implement a servlet in the Python version of Google App Engine?

Comment: In Python, you implement a RequestHandler. See here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html

You'll probably want to implement 'post' in addition to (or instead of) 'get' for the servlet handling this path.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using blobstore to store the files on GAE?

If so, each blobstore entity has a property filename. Before you submit the form to your blobstore handler, do a query for that filename using BlobInfo.gql(query_string, *args, **kwds): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass.html#BlobInfo_gql

For the "servlet" you can just write the request handler that will output 0 or 1 in response to a filename that is submitted.

Additionally, if you only want one file per user/organization with that file name, you may want to store a separate list of uploaded files and corresponding users/organizations and query that instead.